# My jest test not passing unless i had () but then my functions doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

In the code below, if i put `@change="filterLogs"`, my test won't pass. But if i had the parentheses instead like that : `@change="filterLogs()"` my test will pass **BUT** when i run the app my function won't work anymore.

I am trying to test if my function is called when the change event is triggered.

Here's the error that my test didn't pass when i remove the **()**

[console test error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5mj7.png)

What am i doing wrong ? Thanks a lot for your help.

```
<template>
  <div id="search-container">
    <b-row class="align-items-center">
      <b-col md="5">
        <b-input-group>
        <b-form-input v-model="filterModel.searchQuery" @keyup.enter.native="filterLogs" placeholder="Enter the text to filter the logs" ></b-form-input>
          <b-input-group-append>
            <b-button v-on:click="filterLogs()" variant="success">Filter</b-button>
          </b-input-group-append>
        </b-input-group>
      </b-col>
      <b-col md="auto">
        <DateRange @dateRange="updateDateRange" />
      </b-col>
      <b-col md="auto">
        <b-form-checkbox v-model="filterModel.logTypeFilter.critical" @change="filterLogs"> Critical</b-form-checkbox>
      </b-col>
      <b-col md="auto">
        <b-form-checkbox v-model="filterModel.logTypeFilter.error" @change="filterLogs"> Errors</b-form-checkbox>
      </b-col>
      <b-col md="auto">
        <b-form-checkbox v-model="filterModel.logTypeFilter.warning" @change="filterLogs"> Warnings</b-form-checkbox>
      </b-col>  
    </b-row>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Test code**

let wrapper;

```
beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(SearchFilter, {
        propsData: {
            logs : Array
        }
    });
});

test('when any checkbox is checked, filterLogs should be called', () => {
        const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'filterLogs')
        const checkbox =  wrapper.find('b-form-checkbox').trigger('change')
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Comment: Read https://github.com/vuejs/test-utils/issues/775 . In addition I'd need to see the filterLogs function to help fix that breaking issue. Also, the "trigger" method on tests returns a Promise. You need to await it to get meaningful tests

Comment: @Issayah Wow thank you, i had to initialize the spy before the wrapper : i saw this post also for a more visual example : https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/929